# Can't map *.asp to aspnet handler in IIS, keeps using StaticFile handler

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, asp.net, asp-classic, url-routing

Title says it all. I had this working once previously on the same server but cannot for the life of me figure out what is different.  The MVC app is already setup to handle the incoming URL's and reroute them using 301's.  But for that to work, IIS needs to send the classic asp URL's to the ASPNET_ISAPI handler, which it is not doing, it keeps defaulting back to the StaticFileHandler.

[image]
[image]

Comment: A couple things I wanted to mention based on memory helping some developers a year or so back... for the requested path, try `.*` or even `*.MVC`... I don't remember if that's the exact location I specified those values though so that's just an idea.... I remember having to set a setting pointing to the **`~\aspnet_isapi.dll`** path and related to **Limit to: GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG** with an uncheck of the **Verify that file exist** at the application level extension. The wildcard level was at the mapping was at the top level site I think... Follow by an **`IISRESET`**... quick thoughts

Comment: Enable and get a Failed Request Trace and take a look at how the request is being processed, especially the HANDLER_CHANGED event. It may give off a hint as to why the static file handler is being selected. How do these handlers look when the "View Ordered List" action link is selected?